# How to measure Z3's time in Python and are there better Z3 APIs in terms of performance?

Tags: python, c++, api, z3, z3py

It is often said that compiled languages such as C perform better than interpreted languages such as Python. Therefore, I might be interested in migrating Python implementations to C/C++ (assuming they also have access to some Z3 API that is in use and maintenance).

However, this migration only makes sense in one case: if my performance loss is due to the language and not due to Z3. Therefore, I would like to know if there is any way to know what percentage of execution is being executed by Z3 and what percentage by pure Python.

A very naive possibility would be to use a timer just before and after each call to Z3 in my implementation and add up those times to finally see how much of the total those times represent. A sketch of this idea (pseudo-code):

```
timer_total = 0
time_z3 = 0
while executing:
   time_local = take_time()
   call_z3()
   time_z3 += take_time() - time_local
print(time_z3/time_total)
```

This, even though it is an ugly solution, would answer my first question: **how long does Z3 take over the total execution**.

However, I would want to get even more information, if possible: I want to know not only how long Z3 takes to do its computations, but also whether using Python causes Z3 to have to do large data transformations before the information arrives "pure" (i.e., as if I wrote it in Z3) to Z3 and that, therefore, Z3's time has been considerably more than it would be if it didn't have to do them. In other words: **I would like to know how long Z3 is only with the part of doing the logical calculations (not transformations and other processes)**, but only looking for models.

Specifically: I want to know if other languages like C++ do these transformations cheaper and therefore **is the Z3 API of some other language more recommended/effective/optimized than Python**.

I know it's abstract, but I hope the question was understood, and if not, we can discuss it in the comments.

Comment: There's no doubt that C/C++ will be faster: The Python API goes through the C/C++ layer; so you'll have gotten rid of the extra indirection. But, in any reasonable project, solver time will dominate everything else. And you also have to factor in the cost of maintaining your project which is now coded at a much lower level. So,  it may not be worth the effort. In my mind, the only time to switch to C/C++ is if you are building something bigger on top of z3, and thus need access to internals that are not available otherwise. Of course, your mileage might vary.

Comment: To answer your other question: I don't believe there's any easy way to measure the time taken. You'll probably have to either instrument z3 code itself to print parseable timing data; or print logs in detail level and parse it out to figure out how much time is spent where. Try running z3 with verbosity turned higher.

Comment: Thanks a lot for both answers! I will post an own answer in case I find a (not too naive) way to measure Z3's time!